# Get element position() regardless of parent

Tags: xml, xslt, position

Lets say you have an xml document like

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <element />
        <element />
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <element />
        <element />
    </parent>
</parents>
```

While processing I need to know that the elements are `1, 2, 3, 4` in the document, not that but calling `position()` will return `1, 2, 1, 2`.  Normally I would modify the xml, but, in this case, it is not possible, while I am processing parent 2, I somehow need to know that it's first element, is really element `3`.

Thanks,
-c

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and truly XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use [`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#number)**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="element">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:number level="any" count="element"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <element />
        <element />
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <element />
        <element />
    </parent>
</parents>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <element>1</element>
        <element>2</element>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <element>3</element>
        <element>4</element>
    </parent>
</parents>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it's actually quite simple

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::element)"/>
```

Comment: This will not be correct if an `<element>` contains another `<element>`

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, in my situation it won't, but I used your solution in my code anyhow.

Comment: +1 Another approach. For nested `element` you could use: `count(preceding::element|ancestor::element)`. But, do note that for complex hierarchy restrictions (counting not from the whole tree but from some ancestor) the expression could become very complex. For that is xsl:number/@level and xsl:number/@from.